# GDI+ and system graphics cards

Tags: c#

From my research I have seen that `GDI+` (if i am wrong correct me please) is used by `Graphics` to draw various object, but also to my knowledge I am unsure if it utilizes the systems graphics card? If it does not could someone please lead me to a way that I can tell it to utilize the graphics cards many features, like the shader etc, or at-least how to code my own DirectX, OpenGL engine?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. The main thing I wish to complete is to draw a pixel by pixel representation of various object.

Comment: What have you tried to find for yourself? If it's relatively easy hardware rendering you're looking for, take a look at [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx).

Comment: I am trying to create my own, my intention is to learn how to access the hardware not to piggie-back of someone else's creation :)

Comment: You do not want direct hardware access, because then your product will only run on one series of GPU's (if you even manage to draw something). DirectX / OpenGL / XNA / GDI are abstraction layers for this.

Comment: From the online site: "GDI+ interacts with device drivers on behalf of applications. "

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I may venture and try OpenGL, and thank you to Steve, I will go to the site and read it! I just was not sure that it (GDI+) would utilize my Graphics or other graphics cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDI+ and DirectX are two alternative libraries used to render graphics on your display on top of the windows operating system. Since, they are just interfaces to the OS, none of them can directly "talk" to your graphics card at the hardware level. All GDI+ functionality used to draw graphics such as your WinForms graphics, either directly or indirectly is just a call to the API in gdi32.dll system library. Similarly, DirectX functions too have their own API libraries to call.

It is often suggested that DirectX has much better performance in rendering 3D graphics, though in no way does it mean that GDI+ is lacking in any functionality or it doesn't make use your graphics card - they both do indirectly through windows. For comparison, all WinForms graphics in .NET are based on GDI+ library, whereas WPF ones are based on DirectX.

Answer (score 6):

No, I'm sorry. GDI+ does is not hardware-accelerated, and hence does not use graphics cards (although GDI is hardware-accelerated in [windows 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface#Windows_7)). I suggest you use [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/).